# jQuery select element inside of fellow div, but not others

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have four text boxes all with similar code. Each one on hover fades out and displays an image behind it via CSS3 transition. But with the box's title I need the same thing to occure so I wrote a small chunk of code to do this. The only issue I can't solve is getting the hover title effect to work for only its fellow `<section>` partner. I know I can write 4 different chunks of code to do this each having different classes, but that's annoying and if I don't have to I'd rather not.

**My html:**

```
<section class="home-text-box services" >
    <div class="txt-box-title">
        <h2 class="align-left">
            <a class="txtbox-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/services" class="txt-box font-droid" title="Services" alt="Services" >What We Offer</a>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/services" ><div class="services-img"></div></a>
    <a class="txtbox-img txtbox-main-img" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/services" > <?php the_post_thumbnail('txt-box'); ?> </a>

</section>
```

The CSS part is working great when hovering over images I get the fade out effect I was looking for. Now I just want to select the "txtbox-main-img" class of the `<a>` tag when hovering over the `<txt-box-title>` `<a>` tag.

My jQuery is selecting all of the boxes, obviously, because they have the same class. But I'd rather not write 4 different pieces of hover code if I don't have to.

**My jQuery**

```
$('.txtbox-link').hover(function(){
    $('.txtbox-main-img').css('opacity' , '0.0');
},function(){
    $('.txtbox-main-img').removeAttr("style");
});
```

**My CSS in case it is needed:**

```
.txtbox-main-img {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 100;
    transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.txtbox-main-img:hover {
    opacity: .01;
    transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

div.services-img {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('images/services-img.jpg');
    width: 200px;
    height: 122px;
    top: -1px;
z-index: -10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
$('.txt-box-title').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.txtbox-main-img').css('opacity' , '0.0');
},function(){
    $(this).siblings('.txtbox-main-img').removeAttr("style");
});
```

The above works on the assumption that you want to perform the same actions as you posted in your `hover()` code on the `.txtbox-main-img` element while hovering over the `.txt-box-title` element.

I'd suggest, though, that instead of directly manipulating the `style` of the element, that you add, and remove, a class to manipulate the presentation:

```
$('.txt-box-title').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.txtbox-main-img').addClass('faded');
},function(){
    $(this).siblings('.txtbox-main-img').removeClass('faded');
});
```

And define the faded class in your CSS:

```
.faded {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

References:

- [`addclass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the fast response! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @user1253539, thank you very much; glad to have been of help! =)